# Angular post method with int params?

Tags: angular, http, url, post, rest

I am trying to pass three parameters with Angular for my backend with my post method. All three parameters should be integers, one number each. It just doesn't want to work.
Here is what I got so far:

**data.service.ts**

```
  bookRoom(user_id, room_id, date_id) {
    
    return this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/bookRoom/',user_id +'/'+ room_id +'/'+ date_id);
  }
```

**bookroom.component.ts** (Passing params to data.service.ts)

```
  bookRoom() {
    this.dataService.bookRoom(1,2,4).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
  }
```

I want it to be just that simple, just take my three parameters and put them into my post method. Is there any way I can make it work that way?

My url should look like, for example:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/bookRoom/1/2/4
```

I would be very happy if you could show me how to implement this in Angular. Thanks a lot!

[image]

Problem with passing a string:

[image]

Comment: why not just put them in the url with interpolation then? `return this.http.post(\`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/bookRoom/${user_id }/${room_id} /${date_id}\`)`

Comment: Thank you for your comment and your time! Unfortunately it throws me an error ```Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 4```. Is there any other way I could implement this in Angular?

Comment: how could it "get 4"? I only passed a string to the `post` method

Comment: I edited my post and there I uploaded a picture with the error, I really hope you can help me with it. It is in data.service.ts.

Comment: Oh ok so it's 1 not 4 so you can pass whatever you want as body or just leave it empty --e.g: `return this.http.post(\`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/bookRoom/${user_id }/${room_id} /${date_id}\`, {})`

Comment: Thank you soo much! I didn't know that would work either. Thank you again so much Sir, I was really stuck with this problem for many hours! You are really awesome, I wish you good health and take care of yourself! :)

Comment: Haha glad I could help :-) I'll provide it as an answer too so you can mark it as solved

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? I noticed that any user without admin rights can access this route. Is there any way I can prevent this? I am using Laravel backend, is it possible to implement this in Angular? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use the route guards: https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access. But I suggest you to ask another question with the details :-)

Comment: Thank you a lot my friend! You really are awesome. God bless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the string interpolation to do that (with an empty body since it's required for the post method) --e.g:

```js
return this.http.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/bookRoom/${user_id }/${room_id} /${date_id}`, {})
```

Comment: Definitely solved my problem, super and helpful answer!